# How to constrain a type parameter as a subset of another type in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have a type that defines all the services in my app, something like this:

```
type Services = {
    service0: () => string;
    service1: () => string;
}
```

I'd like to write a function that accepts a type that's a subset of this `Services` type (eg: contains zero or more fields from `Services`, but not other fields). So this is a correct type:

```
type Subset = {
    service0: () => string;
}
```

I've tried to use `Partial` for this purpose:

```
const someFn = <S extends Partial<Services>>(subset: S) => {
    console.log("some function");
}
```

and this works:

```
someFn<Subset>({
    service0: () => "foo"
})
```

but the problem is that `someFn` will accept any field I add to `Subset`:

```
type Subset = {
    service0: () => string;
    lofasz: number;
}

someFn<Subset>({
    service0: () => "foo",
    lofasz: 1
})
```

is there a way to constrain the `subset` parameter in `someFn` to only accept a type that has common fields with `Services`?

Comment: There might be some confusion about sub- and super-types. The subtype has additional properties: it's a narrower (more specific) type than the one with fewer properties.

Comment: Yeah, you're using "subtype" in the opposite sense from what it means in the TS type system.  Why do you want generics or care about excess properties anyway, for this?  Can you demonstrate specifically what goes wrong if you just make `test` a specific (non-generic) function accepting `Partial<Services>` as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NdyyQm)?  I'm trying to distinguish between some personal preference or misconception on your part and some well-defined type system issue.

Comment: I fixed my question. So I need generics because this will be used in a factory function, and this type expresses all the services that can be injected into my business functions. I want those places to have compiler errors in case somebody tries to refer to services that don't exist in the context (eg: not listed in `Services`).

Comment: You can make separate "container" types for each of the services, too. No need to try to make a super container and then try to pull out various pieces. As long as the passed in object matches at least the function's parameter type, it will work.

Comment: Instead of describing the problem with words, could you demonstrate with code?  I'm having a hard time seeing the problem when I look at [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NdyyQm); how would a factory function make this worse?  Like, specifically, with code?

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need generics or inheritance for this. You can make different container interfaces or types to have the effect that you're looking for.

[Here's an example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIBt0GVoDdhIDOAwgPbhyjTIDeAUMo8oXgRAIwBcyOU+S7ANwMmLPmwBM3XvwgThTZqyQBmacogrhAXzp1QkWIhQy27Wnt37w0eEh4aJFulYO3jD8aouKXet0b2ADLAALbAkAAmpkRkFFRQPqIaXJ6yQiKMYrJSaZI6ejAAriAIYMDkyOhhERDRGoQAchB1dQAU2WyE3CHhUTEQJORglCDQAJRJWQ0AdJ0CgsgA9EvIM+uZyJsryNBQpInAMMglCKShoRA2kTPbq-ODcxoqfnQ7GIYgcOW4EAA0yDAAAtSEUAOZAwFA4CEZBnIroSJwuBFFjIUJFBCQs4gYqECogZCRCAAByukVAYOQlQAnqDEmdQgAjUDfAmEda3AJ2FAYbANOIjBJOCAAD0gIEisN6tXqXkGgtG1HoigeajyqgKb1WAEkieQAORgKrAADWKAABmAaWSLbCSuhBrC4EzCKR0EVIOgacgxkRCHAoDSAUzPcg6UU4aDEcg4Og3fqoTDbjsk7CEHBCXGE2CIMbQfnjkDM0jiWTJZTqYTgSgy8DqcdQ8B0GAALRFEmAm2DbXIUPGiPMcqYfUgI2+lpI3NjKAEDl0a1ktCYAZDeIzlQAVXxIDBABVu7CALxTJTy1IDDKqxzqeXyTZq2+yLSvRcoGX9AXDJVQbeUg9kseyAAAoEKaAA8fKroqCRbju+6HgCBoPOwBrIAAPsgyGOAaAB8ghAA)

```
interface AllServicesContainer {
    service1: Service1;
    service2: Service2;
    service3: Service3;
}

interface Service1 {

}

interface Service2 {

}

interface Service3 {
    
}

interface LimitedServicesContainer {
    service1: Service1;
    service2: Service2;
}

function limitedServicesNeeded(services: LimitedServicesContainer) {
    services.service1; // ...
    
    // error if uncommented.
    // services.service3
}

// Alternative, though this could cause much confusion depending on your combinations...
interface AllServicesContainer2 extends LimitedServicesContainer {
    service3: Service3;
}

// I don't like `type`s unless absolutely necessary, but you could also do this.
//  this can also get out of hand depending on the depth of built-up types
// but you still don't need generics.
type AllServicesContainer3UsingTypes = {
    service1: Service1;
    service2: Service2;
    service3: Service3;
}

// this is similar to the partial you attempted, but it's picking the properties
// it wants from the `AllServicesContainer3UsingTypes` definition.
type LimitedServicesContainerUsingTypes = Pick<AllServicesContainer3UsingTypes, 'service1' | 'service2'>;

function limitedServicesNeededUsingTypes(services: LimitedServicesContainerUsingTypes) {
    services.service1; // ...
    
    // error if uncommented.
    // services.service3
}
```